# Pending Transaction with Low Gas Stuck for 22 Hours: Seeking Solutions for Cancellation or Completion

Tags: cpp-ethereum, pending-transactions

I attempted a transaction 22 hours ago with a low gas offer due to insufficient ETH, but the transaction has been pending since and I can't seem to cancel it. MetaMask indicates there's not enough gas for cancellation. Previously, I heard that MyEtherWallet's website allowed for offline sending, but I can't find that option now. This was my attempt to purchase something through Uniswap with ETH, and I'm stuck without a solution. I tried sending to my own MetaMask account to resolve this without success. Any advice on resolving this without further expenses would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can send a transaction to your own account with higher gas using an empty value, like 0 ETH. Make sure that the nonce used is the latest the same as the one you used for your pending transaction.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the transaction still hasn't been canceled, and the fee from that transaction hasn't been returned to me.

Answer (score 0):

A pending transaction cannot be cancelled. It can only be replaced by another pending transaction in the mempool.

If you no longer wish to execute your Uniswap transaction, you can follow [Adam Boudj's suggestion](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/162071/pending-transaction-with-low-gas-stuck-for-22-hours-seeking-solutions-for-cance/162088?noredirect=1#comment176561_162071). Send zero ETH to your own wallet using a higher gas price while maintaining the same nonce as the Uniswap transaction. Even if you don't have sufficient gas to complete the transaction, it's not an issue. Your pending transaction will replace the existing one in the mempool. When the network's gas price drops low enough, your pending transaction, which is a zero ETH transfer, will be executed. Your Uniswap transaction will NOT be executed.

If you need to use your wallet for another transaction while your zero ETH transfer is pending, simply send the new transaction with the same nonce and a higher gas price.

Note that to replace the old transaction, you'll need to increase AT LEAST the priority fee, and if desired, the base fee.